# Firebase NullPointerException

Tags: android, firebase, nullpointerexception

Now that i finally got Firebase connected im having a Problem with The Authentification. Its a NullpointerException in Line 47 but i dont get why, maybe im just overlooking something or i cannot find the issue

Stacktrace:

```
05-14 20:57:52.413 8315-8315/com.github.compete E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                              Process: com.github.compete, PID: 8315
                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.github.compete/com.github.compete.MainActivityMenu}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                  at com.github.compete.MainActivityMenu.onCreate(MainActivityMenu.java:47)
                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351) 
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389) 
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

Code in Line 47:`findViewById(R.id.nav_camera).setOnClickListener(this);`

I dont see the problem, maybe i should stop for today.
-Thanks

Comment: nothing related to Firebase here. There is no `R.id.nav_camera` view in your <whateever> layout at the time you are calling `findViewById`

Answer (score 0):

There is no view having as id `nav_camera` in your view.

Comment: Yeah i got it. after sleeping a day i now feel like an idiot xD Thanks